# Bizdays doesn't exclude weekends

Tags: r, group-by, bizdays, gapply

I am trying to calculate utilization rates by relative employee lifespans. I need to assign a total number of hours available to this employee between the earliest and furthest date in which time was recorded. From there I will use this as the divisor in utilization rate = workhours / totalhours.

When testing the bizdays function, I tried a simple example.

```
bizdays::bizdays("2020-02-07","2020-02-14")
[1] 7
```

Any reason why the function is not returning the correct number of business days? 
I am expecting 5 business days since 2/07 was a Friday so only 1 week should be included.

The goals is to use bizdays in the following function that will be applied to a grouped df with gapply.

```
timeentry = function(x){
  end_date = max(x$terminus)#creates an end_date variable from further end date in the group
  start_date = min(x$onset) #creates a start_date from earliest start date in the group
  start_date %>% bizdays(end_date) * 8 #subtracts dates and multiple by 8 to get work hours between two dates
}
```

I will apply the function in this manner. Unfortunately, it returns an error suggesting it cannot allocate vector of size 4687 gb. This is a separate issue I hope someone can point out.

```
util = group %>% gapply(.,timeentry)
```

where group is the grouped df.

Comment: Try `bizdays::bizdays("2020-02-07","2020-02-14", "weekends")` -- you'll need to set a  specific calendar to reflect holidays and such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting up your calendar with `create.calendar`

```
library(bizdays)
create.calendar(name = "demo", weekdays = c("saturday", "sunday"))
bizdays::bizdays("2020-02-07","2020-02-14", cal = "demo")
[1] 5
```

Comment: I thought bizdays had a default calendar which didn't make this necessary. I will give it a shot

Comment: it has the `weekends` calendar, but that's not the default.